# Admob in phonegap android click anywhere in footer and header its only opening browser

Tags: android, phonegap-plugins

I am implementing android admob in phone-gap app.I have used AdMob smartphone web code .its showing ad(advertisement) but when I click at footer or header its only goes to browser and shows about blank .my app is totally messed because of admob.
I have followed this link:-
http://support.google.com/admob/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1704625
I am using this JS file:-
http://mm.admob.com/static/iphone/iadmob.js

Please tell me where I am going wrong.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

It says:
"Please note that we are closing down AdMob Smartphone Web on May 1, 2012 and consolidating it with the main Google AdSense for content product. If you would like to monetize a mobile website, we strongly encourage you to either sign up for or log in to your AdSense account at http://adsense.google.com. From there, you can generate the right ad tag for your mobile site."

on the website. They are probably closed and it will not work.